# src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tab:codigoUnidGestora' to a(n) 'type definition' component.xsd(src-resolve)

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to convert xsd to php but I am getting this error in the process:

problem

[image: 1]

> src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tab:codigoUnidGestora' to a(n) 'type definition' component.xsd(src-resolve)

my main file
Educacao.xsd

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/sagresEdu" version="1.0"
xml:lang="pt-BR"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:edu="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/sagresEdu"
xmlns:gen="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/genericos"
xmlns:tab="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/tabelasInternas"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/genericos"
    schemaLocation="Genericos.xsd" />
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/tabelasInternas"
    schemaLocation="tabelasInternas.xsd" />

    ...

<xsd:complexType name="cabecalho_t">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="codigoUnidGestora" type="tab:codigoUnidGestora"/>
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="nomeUnidGestora" type="gen:nomeUnidGestora_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="cpfContador" type="gen:cpfContador_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="cpfGestor" type="gen:cpfGestor_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="anoReferencia" type="gen:anoReferencia_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="mesReferencia" type="gen:mesReferencia_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="versaoXml" type="gen:versaoXml_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="diaInicPresContas" type="gen:diaInicPresContas_t" />
        <xsd:element nillable="false" name="diaFinaPresContas" type="gen:diaFinaPresContas_t" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="educacao_t">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="PrestacaoContas" type="edu:cabecalho_t" />
        <xsd:element name="escola" type="edu:escola_t" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="atendimento" type="edu:atendimento_t" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<!-- ROOT -->
<xsd:element name="educacao" type="edu:educacao_t">
    <xsd:unique name="chaveAluno">
        <xsd:selector xpath="edu:escola/edu:turma/edu:matricula/edu:aluno" />
        <xsd:field xpath="edu:cpfAluno" />
    </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

tabelasInternas.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace= 
"http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2023/xml/tabelasInernas" 
version="1.0" xml:lang="pt-BR" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:edu="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/sagresEdu">
<xsd:simpleType name="codigoUnidGestora">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="201031"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="201050"/>        
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType> 
</xsd:schema>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working, because apparently the types are being called correctly.
I am not able to understand why some of the elements are not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your import is for the namespace `namespace="http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2022/xml/tabelasInternas"` (note the 2022) yet the tabelasInternas has the target namespace `http://www.tce.se.gov.br/sagres2023/xml/tabelasInernas` (note the 2023) so the namespaces simply don't match. I don't know whether that is just a typo in one of the documents or whether there are different versions of those schemas, but the error message is correct, you don't have a matching import, due to the namespace differences.